# Lebesgue integration of a sine function

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to understand this problem but it does not go very well. I don't understand how I should calculate this integral, when I'm given the density function. Read the problem below:

"Let $\lambda$ be a Borel measure on the interval $[0;\infty)$ given by the density function $\exp(-x)$ with respect to the 1-dim. Lebesgue measure. Evaluate the following integral 
$$\begin{equation}
\int_{[0;\infty)} \sin(x)d\lambda(x)
\end{equation}$$
"

Should I consider the problem as follows
$$\begin{equation}
\int_{[0;\infty)} e^{-x}\sin(x)d\lambda(x)
\end{equation}$$
Because if I solve the integral by Riemann, then I get the pretty result as:$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Am I on the right track? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second integral in your post should be $\int_{[0;\infty)} e^{-x} \sin x \, dx$ since you have converted the integral with respect to the $\lambda$ measure into an integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Other than this typo, the final result is correct.

Comment: Yea that's true, my mistake. Can you please explain how I can evaluate it? I know how to do it in the Riemann way, but not the other way.

Comment: Since your function is continuous, I believe the Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral are the same.

Comment: Yea, but I'm taking an integration theory course, so my teacher want us to use the methods from the course, so I don't think we should use Riemann method.